# How can I remove http://p.chango.com/static/c.js from my site?

Tags: malware, malware-removal, adware, malware-detection

I found some code injected somehow on my site. It links to

```
<script src="http://p.chango.com/static/c.js.
```

1. How can I get rid of it?
2. Is this coming from my browser? Mind you, I see it in different browsers and PCS.
3. is my share hosting provider infected?

Answer (score 1):

This may be injected by your shared hosting provider itself. If you're seeing it on multiple computers and browsers, the likelihood of it being malware is slim. Some shared hosts have things like this, especially if it is a free host. I'm not a Javascript expert, but it looks like this code is adding a further JS file to your header, probably not a real JS file but more of a "pixel" such as is used in internet traffic tracking.

Answer (score 0):

[That script from chango.com doesn't seem to be malware, but is a tracker.](https://www.ghostery.com/apps/chango) Since it is a [tracker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_analytics), it is possible that your hosting provider injected it on purpose.

Installing [**Ghostery**](https://www.ghostery.com) or another anti-tracker browser extension on your browser will disable it from being executed by your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem but I solved it from this Randy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358371/all-browsers-loading-external-js-files-http-netloader-cc-run-js-http-p-cha/13807984#13807984).

> got rid of the p.chango.com script by going to their website and clicking "opt out." It does not appear to be a very dangerous script but does track your searching and browsing for "target marketing purposes."
>
> I removed an unknown extension "SelectionLinks 1.5" and that got rid of netloader.cc. It appears to be attached to a number of extensions so just look for the ones you don't know what they do. Personally I am blocking all content from their host server at 205.234.175.175. If you do the same tell the parent company at www.cachefly.com.
>
> The trustworthy extension "noscript" is very good at blocking these scripts as well as letting you know the sneaky buggers are there in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

Hey man this is just a company that they sell advertisements go in to their website and press opt out at the bottom of the page ! then you are good to go